# Mousemove is not triggered after my page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a jquery fullpage plugin + an image with a kind of magnifying glass when mouse is hovering. It works as expected in the following scenario:

- The mouse is hover the dentist image (the magnifying glass is visible)
- The I scroll down (or press down key)
- The I scroll up (or press up key) without moving the mouse at the same time
  (I'm still hovering the dentist image but not moving my mouse)
- Then I start moving my mouse again >> the magnifying glass is appearing.

The following scenario is problematic:

- The mouse is hover the dentist image (the magnifying glass is visible)
- The I scroll down (or press down key)
- The I scroll up (or press up key) but at the same time I continuously move my mouse, when the scroll end, I still move my mouse hover the image. My magnifying glass is not visible! I had to stop moving for about 1 second then start moving again to have my magnifying glass to appear.

I put some debugging traces in my js and I can clearly see in my console that for the second scenario the mousemove events is not triggered. I had to stop moving for about 1 sec then moving again to have the mousenter+mousemove to trigger.

```
    // Events
    $(this).mouseenter(function () {
        console.log('mouseenter');
        evenZoom.checkImageChanged($(this));
        evenZoom.showLens();
    });
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        console.log('mousemove');
        evenZoom.moveLens(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    });
    $(this).mouseleave(function () {
        console.log('mouseleave');
        evenZoom.hideLens();
    });
```

You can see it here: http://gite-le-refuge.weebly.com/

Comment: What browser are you testing on? Seems to work for me in Chrome (44.0.2403.125)

Comment: The problem occurs only with Google Chrome (44.0.2403.130) not with Internet Explorer. Please be sure to continuously move the mouse when scrolling up. You'll see that the magnifying glass will not be immediately visible. You'll need to stop moving, then start moving again for the magnifying glass to appear.

Comment: Can't reproduce in firefox (39.0.3). Works fine for me

Comment: @JiFus thanks for testing in Firefox. Only Google Chrome seems to be problematic. Hope someone can explain me why the behaviour with GC.

Comment: Yep when i move the mouse constantly I see the issue, its a strange one. I'll play around with it some more to see if I can help you with any other info.

Comment: @Stacey Burns: is there any workaround for that ? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not that I can find. I searched for related issues and found a few posts on Chrome not triggering mouse enter events when scrolling but are from 2010 so probably not reliable.  Sorry I cant help any more.